# Inno Setup Checking for running process

Tags: inno-setup

I have a Inno Setup project that I want to check if the application is actually running before uninstalling it. I tried many ways but it all fails silently, when running in Windows 7. For example the following script that checks for `notepad.exe` process using `psvince.dll` always returns `false` regardless of Notepad being running or not.

I used `psvince.dll` in a C# app to check, if it works under Windows 7 and it works without any problem. So my best guess is that installer can not run correctly with UAC enabled.

```pascal
[Code]
function IsModuleLoaded(modulename: String): Boolean;
external 'IsModuleLoaded@files:psvince.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
   if(Not IsModuleLoaded('ePub.exe')) then
   begin
       MsgBox('Application is not running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
       Result := true;
   end
   else
   begin
       MsgBox('Application is already running. Close it before uninstalling.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
       Result := false;
   end
end;
```

Comment: I have the same Problem, but the AnsiString did not help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using Unicode Inno Setup? If you are, it should say

```
function IsModuleLoaded(modulename: AnsiString): Boolean;
```

since psvince.dll isn't a Unicode dll.

Also the example checks for epub.exe, not notepad.exe.

Comment: I have the same Problem, but the AnsiString did not help me.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try to use WMIService:

```pascal
procedure FindApp(const AppName: String);
var
  WMIService: Variant;
  WbemLocator: Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WMIService := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');
  WbemObjectSet :=
    WMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where Name="' + AppName + '"');
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    Log(AppName + ' is up and running');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Inno Setup actually has an AppMutex directive, which is documented in the help. Implementing it requires 2 lines of code.

In the [Setup] section of your iss file you add:

```
AppMutex=MyProgramsMutexName
```

And then during your application startup add this line of code:

```
CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "MyProgramsMutexName");
```

Comment: [Official doc](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?mutexsessions) says, that you need two mutexes, to detect instances, launched by other users.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code to check if notepad.exe is running.

```
[Code]
function IsAppRunning(const FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  FWMIService: Variant;
  FSWbemLocator: Variant;
  FWbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := false;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WBEMScripting.SWBEMLocator');
  FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process Where Name="%s"',[FileName]));
  Result := (FWbemObjectSet.Count > 0);
  FWbemObjectSet := Unassigned;
  FWMIService := Unassigned;
  FSWbemLocator := Unassigned;
end;

function InitializeSetup: boolean;
begin
  Result := not IsAppRunning('notepad.exe');
  if not Result then
  MsgBox('notepad.exe is running. Please close the application before running the installer ', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: How is this different from [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24181158/960757) ? Well, it is. You don't need to assign `Unassigned` to the objects since they will be *released* when they go out of scope of the function. And you should check for assignment after you run the query (`VarIsNull` in the other post). So, the other post is a bit shorter and more precise.

Comment: I've been using this code successfully for ages until today when one user who hadn't seen any error messages before suddenly started seeing two error messages "ShellExecuteEx Failed; code 299. Only part oif a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed." and "Runtime Error (at 1:321); SWbemlocator: Access is denied."