# Inno uninstall issue

Tags: while-loop, inno-setup, uninstallation

I am not able to stop uninstallation when the application, any process related is running. As a result all files are not deleted completely. 
I need a way to check whether the application is running or not during uninstallation, prompt a message to user to close the application and then Uninstall.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Innosetup checking for running process in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363035/innosetup-checking-for-running-process-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

Use the AppMutex directive to check for a mutex held by the app.
Inno will then stop the uninstall until the app has shutdown.