# How to delay continuation of Uninstall after it deletes files?

Tags: installation, sleep, inno-setup, delay, uninstallation

My Uninstall script exits the running app however it is not completely gone (due to timing issue) and therefore the following UninstallDelete section does not delete the {app} folder since it is not empty. If I exit the app manually and then run the uninstall script then the {app} folder gets deleted fine.

[UninstallDelete]
Name: {app}; Type: dirifempty

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions to delay the attempt the remove the {app} folder.  I thought of using the Inno Setup's built-in procedure called Sleep but I could not figure out how and where to use it (e.g. couldn't call it from [UninstallRun] section. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could hook the `function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;` or `procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);` function.

This runs before uninstall starts, you can place a check here to make sure the application is not running.   Using `FindWindowByClassName` or `FindWindowByWindowsName`

If you find it running you could prompt the user to close the application.
When the user says's it's closed you could then call `Sleep()` to give it enough time to close, before checking again to make sure the application is really closed.

If your application creates a `Mutex` when it's running, you could use `CheckFormMutexes` 
as an alternative to the `FindWindowXXX` calls.

Another option is addressed in this question: [Inno Setup Checking for running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363035/innosetup-checking-for-running-process-in-windows-7)

Regardless of the detection method calling `Sleep` to wait would resolve this problem.