# Is it possible to check if program is already running before trying to install it? (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to create the installer. When I launch the installer I've created I need to check whether the program I'm trying to install is already running or not and if it is running then I have to show the corresponding message until I close it or exit.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is your application, make it create a mutex. Then you can use [`AppMutex` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex).

```
[Setup]
AppMutex=MyProgMutex
```

[image]

---

If you cannot modify the application, you need to code the check for running application in Inno Setup. You can for example use `IsAppRunning` function from the answer by @RRUZ to [How to check with Inno Setup, if a process is running at a Windows 2008 R2 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9941293/850848) in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Answer: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  while IsAppRunning('MyProg.exe') do
  begin
    Answer := MsgBox('Program is running, please close it', mbError, MB_OKCANCEL);
    if Answer = IDCANCEL then
    begin
      Result := False
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

*Based on a similar question on uninstaller:

[Preparing to Uninstall like Preparing to Install Page - Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55121683/850848)*